# Bootable GRUB partition

Tags: linux, grub, liveusb

I have a customized live Fedora 12 USB flash drive which is working fine. What I want to do is to make a partition of my hard disk drive bootable so that my customized Fedora can be run from the hard disk drive. To accomplish this I did the following steps:

1. Created a primary partition (/dev/sda2), formatted it as ext3 and set it as active.
2. Copied all the files in the live USB flash drive to /dev/sda2. Following are the live USB flash drive contents (all directories):

   a. boot
   b. EFI
   c. LiveOS
   d. syslinux
3. I then installed the GRUB in `boot/grub`
4. Created the grub.conf in `boot/grub`

The following are the contents of each directory in the USB flash drive:

```
syslinux/
  boot.cat
  isolinux.bin
  splash.jpg
  vesamenu.c32
  initrd0.img
  ldlinux.sys
  syslinux.cfg
  vmlinuz0

LiveOS/
  livecd-iso-to-disk
  osmin.img
  squashfs.img

EFI/
  boot/
     boot.conf
     grub.conf
     boot.efi
     bootia32.conf
     bootia32.efi
     splash.jpg
     splash.xpm.gz
     vesamenu.c32
     initrd0.img
     isolinux.bin
     isolinux.cfg
     vmlinuz0

boot/grub/
   core GRUB files
   grub.conf
   olpc.fth
```

The following is the contents of `grub.conf`.

```
default=0
splashimage=/EFI/boot/splash.xpm.gz
timeout 2 hiddenmenu

title funLinux
kernel /EFI/boot/vmlinuz0
root=live:LABEL=myFun
rootfstype=auto ro liveimg quiet
ssb.blacklist=1 selinux=0 vga=normal
nomodeset rhgb    initrd
/EFI/boot/initrd0.img
```

Now when I try to boot from the hard disk it shows the GRUB menu and Fedora starting to load but during loading it said:

> No root device found Boot has failed,
>   sleeping forever

So, where is the problem? What I am doing wrong?

Kindly refer me any book/articles about file/directory hierarchy on live USB flash drives and their working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel line in your grub config has the argument "root=live:LABEL=myFun" - I'm assuming that syntax is valid, even though it looks strange to me. But It appears that it's looking for a disk labelled "myFun".  Did you set that label on /dev/sda2?

You might try changing that to "root=/dev/sda2", or maybe "root=live:/dev/sda2" (perhaps that "live:" syntax is some Fedora thing).